# Firebase database simultaneous connections

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, price, multiple-users

Firebase says it can have only 100k users simultaneously for spark plan. It also states per database. What does that mean? How can I store data in multiple databases and connect each other? Also it states 1gb data stored. How much will that be approx? Say 1 users data will have 10 childs. So how many users data can be stored at that space? Someone please help me out as google isn't very clear about it.

Comment: title of the question is not specific enough for SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're talking about Realtime Databases and not Cloud Firestore.
The Firebase Spark "Free" Plan includes 100 simultaneous users not 100k. (100k+ users is supported with the Flame plan and Blaze plan).
You can store 1GB worth of data in the Real Time Database, and 100GB worth a month for download. This plan only supports **1** database per project, connecting of multiple databases isn't possible.

It's hard to determine how much "storage" that would take up, due to varying factors. But, a good rule of thumb is that most JSON data doesn't take up a lot of space so you should be good.

I would like to clarify with you that simultaneous users is just the amount of users that can access your database (via any interface or platform) at the same time to a single database.

There's a great documentation on the features and pricing of Firebase [here](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/), and I would also recommend reading some of their [documentation on Realtime Databases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/).

I hope this helps, if you need any more help please let me know.

Comment: In the blaze plan multiple databases are supported... what do they mean by multiple and how do i create multiple databases and link them???

Comment: Your original post said “Spark” plan not “Blaze” plan. If you were meant to write Blaze plan originally I’d recommend you look into Database sharding. Link here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding

Comment: Note that the whole idea behind sharding is that there are no (or at least *very* limited) connections between data in the different databases. If data has "strong" connections, it should be in the same shard. If all data in your app has strong connections, it seems unlikely that sharding it will help.